# Число сказуемого при подлежащем с двумя определениями

Tags: сказуемые, определения, подлежащее

В событиях этой развязки определяются идейная и эстетическая направленность комедии.

Мне кажется, что "идейная и эстетическая" связаны, поэтому направленность в ед. ч. И сказуемое нужно поставить в единственное. Но тогда смущают "идейная и эстетическая", все же две (?) направленности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> смущают "идейная и эстетическая", все же две (?) направленности.

Две, но порознь. ) Разумеется, *определяЕтся идейная и эстетическая направленность*. Потому что "направленность" здесь никак в множественное число не поставишь.